# Python - packages and settings file

Tags: python

I have a python package that needs to pull in settings from my project directory, here is how my project is currently structured:

```
~/Project/bin/mypackage
    - package files
    
~/Project/myproject/
    - project files
    - start.py
    - settings.py
```

I guess it's similar to how Django is structured, you have a `settings.py` file in your project directory that is somehow referenced by the Django system package in your Python directory.

So, if I am running `start.py` like so:

```
python ~/Project/myproject/start.py
```

..and `start.py` imports and utilizes the `mypackage` package, is there any way I can reference the `settings.py` file local to `start.py` from within the package? Would I have to load the settings file in `start.py` and store the values in a global? Does anyone know how this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory containing the script that was used to invoke the python interpreter is added to the `PYTHONPATH`. It is available at `sys.path[0]`. See http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path

This means that `settings` should be available from `mypackage.mymodule` simply by `import settings`.

However, I would consider handling the loading of settings in start.py and structuring your app so that a settings object (perhaps just a dict) is passed to it.

Answer (score 3):

The way I see it you have several options:

1. look for settings and import them either from the current working directory or as determined from environment variables. This is the "django way" using `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and `PYTHONPATH`.  This is nice and magical when it works and inconvenient when it doesn't such as in your case when you are running from a different directory.
2. rely on module search path which will include the directory of the calling package. Nice and simple but the settings will vary based on the caller. For example all you need in `mypackage` is:

   `import settings`
3. pass in `settings` as a variable